# Clarification of rationale for not having tentative definitions

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

C++17 (N4713), C.1.2 Clause 6: basic concepts, 1:

> Change: C++ does not have “tentative definitions” as in C.
>
> Rationale: This **avoids having different initialization rules** for fundamental types and user-defined types.

Question: what are the different initialization rules for fundamental types and user-defined types? Any examples?

---

Extra: here are the mutually referential file-local static objects in C:

```
struct X { int i; struct X* next; };
static struct X a;
static struct X b = { 0, &a };
static struct X a = { 1, &b };
```

In C++ this code is invalid. How to achieve the same in C++?

Comment: Hour long presentation [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis at CppCon 2018.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preferred way to declare things with file scope is an *anonymous namespace*. Everything inside `namespace {}` has file scope. You can declare functions, classes, variables, etc. `extern` works as usual to declare `a`.

Note that in C++ it's not necessary to write `struct X`

```
struct X { int i; X* next; };
namespace {
    extern X a;
    X b = { 0, &a };
    X a = { 1, &b };
}
```

Comment: Re: "file scope": I've just concluded that C++ has no "file scope". Is that correct? N4713 (C++17) uses term "file scope" only 3 times, all related to C (If I'm correct). C++ has, for example, "global namespace scope" (also called "global scope"). So, what scope you've meant?

Comment: @pmor The more formal name for "file scope" is "internal linkage".  Names declared within an anonymous namespace are not accessible from other compilation units, just like global names declared with `static`.

Comment: I think in practice, anonymous namespaces are given random names, or names based on the filename, by the compiler, since some parts of C++ rely on names being unique.

Comment: @user253751 I think this is true for MSVC, but false for gcc and clang (when using Itanium ABI). [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/aonrTM6cq).

Comment: And what if `a` in `extern X a;` needs to be `static`?

Comment: @pmor Putting it inside `namespace {}` is the same as `static` for all intents and purposes.